# Update time format using implode and explode

Tags: php, date, explode, strtotime, implode

I have string as following

```
12:00:00,11:30:00,10:30:00,10:00:00,09:30:00
```

And I need to convert that to

```
12:00,11:30,10:30,10:00,09:30
```

A single value can be converted by using

```
date('H:i',strtotime(explode(',',$req->slots)[0]))
```

Is there any way to do it simple without  iterate over them?

Comment: is it a single string or array of strings?

Comment: @splash58 : single string

Comment: if you do it often Only for information :) - https://eval.in/409238

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could regex it.

```
echo preg_replace('~:\d{2}(,|$)~', '$1', '12:00:00,11:30:00,10:30:00,10:00:00,09:30:00');
```

Ouput:

> 12:00,11:30,10:30,10:00,09:30

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/vW0kN4/2
PHP Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/91d3f2ceb8c7f763e51c32841c4ee201070ab514

Comment: this is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '12:00:00,11:30:00,10:30:00,10:00:00,09:30:00';
$ar = explode(',', $str);

foreach($ar as &$item) 
   $item = substr($item, 0,-3);

echo $str = implode(',', $ar); // 12:00,11:30,10:30,10:00,09:30
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array();
foreach(explode(',', $req->slots) as $time) $result[] = date('H:i',strtotime($time));
$result = implode(',', $result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well... it's sort of not iterating :

```
 var str = "12:00:00,11:30:00,10:30:00,10:00:00,09:30:00";
 var new_str = str.split(",").map(function(x){return x.replace(/^(.*):.*$/, "$1")}).join(",");
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/9kdcaowf/